# Is there a way to test if php code is php < 5.3.2 compatible

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, version

So I'm running XAMPP with php5.6.3 installed. However, I'm writing something for a website running on a server using php 5.2.

Is there anything like PHPUnit or PHPCodesniffer (or an online tool) which will tell me if part of my code won't work on specific versions of php (such as php < 5.3.2)?

Thanks

Comment: If it is a snippet http://3v4l.org/ can show you how your code works in lots of versions of PHP

Comment: https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility

Comment: Both look good. I'll check them out. I think PHPCompatibility is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

CodeSniffer will do:

Download the latest release at http://github.com/wimg/PHP53Compat_CodeSniffer/downloads – make sure you rename the `PHP53Compat_CodeSniffer` directory to `PHP53Compatibilit`y
    If you have git, use :

`git clone git://github.com/wimg/PHP53Compat_CodeSniffer.git PHP53Compatibility`

```
Copy the PHP53Compatibility directory to {your pear path}/PHP/CodeSniffer/Standards
```

**How to run**

Start PHP_CodeSniffer like this :

```
phpcs --standard=PHP53Compatibility <path-to-your-PHP-source-directory>
```

**Sample output**

```
FILE: C:\temp\bla.php

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



FOUND 15 ERROR(S) AND 2 WARNING(S) AFFECTING 12 LINE(S)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



  4 | ERROR   | Function name, class name, namespace name or constant name can

    |         | not be reserved keyword 'goto' (since version 5.3)

  6 | ERROR   | Extension 'dbase' is not available in PHP 5.3 anymore

 12 | ERROR   | Function name, class name, namespace name or constant name can

    |         | not be reserved keyword 'const' (since version all)

 12 | ERROR   | Function name, class name, namespace name or constant name can

    |         | not be reserved keyword 'const' (since version all)
```

etc...

SRC: http://techblog.wimgodden.be/2010/06/24/automated-php-5-3-compatibility-testing-for-your-old-code/

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So after looking into all of the above suggestions I've settled on PHPCompatibility by Wim Godden. https://github.com/wimg/PHPCompatibility

Two reasons I chose this over PHP53Compat_CodeSniffer is:

1. it specifically has a new feature for what I wanted. Taken from Wim's blog:

> You can also test for backwards compatibility of your code by specifying versions like 5.2, which causes it to check whether you’re using functions or keywords not known to this older version. Quite nice if you’re coding on PHP 5.5, but your system engineer tells you half way through the project the project will have to be deployed on 5.2.

That's exactly my case. And...

2. It uses composer and is much simpler to use than PHP53Compat_CodeSniffer.

Comment: This is just a newer version of the same